# How Do I Fill a 2D Array With Perlin Noise?

Tags: java, arrays, perlin-noise

I've devised a small personal project to help me learn how to use Perlin Noise. This project involves filling a 2D array of `r` rows and `c` columns with random, coherent data generated with a Perlin Noise algorithm.

Now, I've just spent hours reading a wide variety of resources about generating Perlin Noise. However, it's all over my head and I'm totally lost. I understand the basic concept, but I don't have a clue how to begin implementing this in Java. I think it would be most helpful if someone could show me some well-commented code that accomplishes my goal so I can work backwards and apply it myself.

Comment: A similar question was asked here that I found useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531019/perlin-noise-in-java

And here's an old Java applet example complete with source code I found http://dzzd.net/demo/PERLINSample/

Answer (score 7):

If you want a *perfectly* documented implementation, check out [this](http://code.j3d.org/javadoc/org/j3d/texture/procedural/PerlinNoiseGenerator.html).  You can download the [source code](http://code.j3d.org/download.html) and open `src\java\org\j3d\texture\procedural\PerlinNoiseGenerator.java` to get your commented code.  I take no credit for any of this.  All I did was hunt around on Google a bit.

Since it's licensed under LGLPL, I'll also provide a [direct link](http://pastie.org/3350566) to it.  (If I'm mistaken about what LGLPL means and my ability to do this, please notify me.)

Answer (score 0):

Processing provides a Perlin noise generator.

[Reference documentation](http://processing.org/reference/noise_.html)

[<strike>Source code</strike>](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java)  look for the `noise(...)` method(s)

Comment: **Processing != Java**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the accepted answer.
[Perlin Noise in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531019/perlin-noise-in-java)
. I am pretty sure this is exactly what you want to do. Just tweak the roughness variable and what is added whenever nextFloat() is called an you got yourself a filled 2d array of Perlin noise.